`gx` mangles URLs by adding a forward slash (`/`) to number sign (`#`) characters
When using gx to open a URL, any # characters in the URL get replaced by /# when the URL is opened in the browser.
For example, placing the cursor over https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link in a Vim buffer and pressing gx results in opening https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax/#link in the browser, which breaks the link.
I wonder if this is because Vim tries to escape the # character for some reason by replacing it with \#, which then gets converted to /# by my browser.
This happens regardless of whether gx is executed from normal mode (with the cursor inside the URL) or visual mode (with the URL highlighted).
I'm currently using Vim 9.1 on Fedora Linux 40, with Firefox as my default browser.
Anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Cannot reproduce. Does it work with a minimal vimrc and without any plugins (except netrw)?

I can, on a different system, with a different browser and without sourcing my config. Vim 9.1.727 with Netrw v172, which is the latest version distributed with Vim. This should be reported.

It should not before verifying that this behaviour is still there. Which isn't since it has been fixed as of this commit

Same version, different code? That's not very clean. @ChristianBrabandt, you should have bumped Netrw's version number as well… or gone through DrChip if he is still around as this is a third-party script.

Dr. Chip retired and we don't have a maintainer for netrw, that's why the version stays the same (but it should have added a last change entry at the top of the file).

I'm going to leave the previous 2 comments for historical context, but let's try to keep comments working as intended.

You could also let the "community" you are so hung up on decide how it wants to use comments.

Commit 2328a39a54 (runtime(netrw): do not double escape Vim special characters, 2024-12-20) resolved this issue, as pointed out in the comments.
If you have Vim version 9.1.0950 or later, this patch should be included (according to git describe --contains 2328a39a54).

When I run Vim it shows version 9.1.919, does that correspond to tag v9.1.0919? So the leading zero is stripped from the patch number?

Yes, that is a padding zero.
